How to add custom JavaScript globally?
How do I add custom JavaScript to an extention so it appears on all pages?

You can implement hook_civicrm_coreResourceList to add your script to the list of items loaded by CiviCRM on every page.

Excatly the hook I was looking for. Thank you!
